# java xpath expression get only value if child node is different

Tags: java, xml, xpath

I woudlike to get one specific value of node if child node is different like present in my expression :

```
DocumentBuilderFactory factory = DocumentBuilderFactory.newInstance();
 DocumentBuilder builder = factory.newDocumentBuilder();
 document = builder.parse(new File("test.xml")); 

List<String> data = new ArrayList<>();
XPath xpath = XPathFactory.newInstance().newXPath();
NodeList nodes = (NodeList) xpath.evaluate("/name1/type/*[name()!= 'pmc']", document, XPathConstants.NODESET);
        for (int i = 0; i < nodes.getLength(); i++) {
            Element el = (Element) nodes.item(i);
            data.add(el.getAttribute("id"));
        }

System.out.println(data);
```

test.xml :

```
<?xml version="1.0" encoding="UTF-8"?>
<name1>
    <type id ="1">
        <coord>67</coord>
        <lmc>57657</lmc>
    </type>
    <lang>
        <eng>989</eng>
        <spa>123</spa>
    </lang>
</name1>
<name2>
    <type id ="2">
        <coord>534</coord>
        <lmc>654654</lmc>
    </type>
    <lang>
        <eng>354</eng>
        <spa>2424</spa>
    </lang>
</name2>
<name3>
    <type>
        <coord>23432</coord>
        <pmc>14324</pmc>
    </type>
    <lang>
        <eng>141</eng>
        <spa>142</spa>
    </lang>
</name3>
```

For example I wouldlike to get only the `id` if the childnode is `'pmc'` and not the others.

Comment: Your xml is invalid (for example `<pmc>14324</umc>`). Can you edit your question and fix it?

Comment: What exactly is the problem? Does your code run? Are there errors? Then post the error message and the full stack trace.

Comment: @vanje No error, I just can't get the data as I wouldlike

Comment: Then you should mention this in your question. And please include the expected result and the actual result. In the predicate do  you mean the function `name()`? Then you should include the parentheses.

Comment: @vanje yes sorry... yes I mean `name()` but it seems `!=` not working..

Comment: First, you still have two `<lmc>xxx</umc>` nodes. Second, `<name3>`'s `<type>` child node does not have an `id` attribute. Is that intentional?

Comment: @JackFleeting No it wasn't intentional, just for my xml test sorry

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Since the question isn't entirely clear, let's try it this way.

Assuming that your xml reads like this:

```
<?xml version="1.0" encoding="UTF-8"?>
<name1>
    <type id ="1">
        <coord>67</coord>
        <lmc>57657</lmc>
    </type>
    <lang>
        <eng>989</eng>
        <spa>123</spa>
    </lang>
</name1>
<name2>
    <type id ="2">
        <coord>534</coord>
        <lmc>654654</lmc>
    </type>
    <lang>
        <eng>354</eng>
        <spa>2424</spa>
    </lang>
</name2>
<name3>
    <type id ="3">
        <coord>23432</coord>
        <pmc>14324</pmc>
    </type>
    <lang>
        <eng>141</eng>
        <spa>142</spa>
    </lang>
</name3>
```

and that you are trying to get the value of the attribute `<id>` of any `<type>`  node which has a `<pmc>` child node, try using the following as your xpath expression:

```
//*/type[pmc]/@id
```